# KendoUI: programmatically setting a datasource model

Tags: datasource, kendo-ui

I would like to set programmatically the model of my datasource.
Something like:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({ //... });

var mod = kendo.data.Model.define({
    fields: data 
});

ds.model = mod;
```

Is it possible? How?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, but you have to set it up in `DataSource` field `schema.model` (see [schema.model reference](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#schemamodel-objectkendodatamodel))

As indicated on this page, you will have something like this :

```
// Definition of your model
var Product = kendo.data.Model.define({
    id: "ProductID",
    fields: {
         ProductID: {
            //this field will not be editable (default value is true)
            editable: false,
            // a defaultValue will not be assigned (default value is false)
            nullable: true
         },
         ProductName: {
             validation: { //set validation rules
                 required: true
             }
         },
         UnitPrice: {
           //data type of the field {Number|String|Boolean|Date} default is String
           type: "number",
           // used when new model is created
           defaultValue: 42,
           validation: {
               required: true,
               min: 1
           }
       }
   }
});

// Map this model to your DataSource object
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    schema: {
        model: Product // Use the existing Product model
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, but does this mean that I have to initialize a new kendo.data.DataSource... each and every time I would like to change its model? I am currently using this technique, but I was wondering if there is a way to override just the model, without reinitializing the entire datasource.

Comment: Perhaps (I have not tried this), could you change it directly via `dataSource.reader.model` as indicated in the last thread of this post : (Kendo UI dynamic schema)[http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/schemaless-data-and-dynamic-schema.aspx].

Comment: Actually this solution does not seem to work: data are not formatted the right way.

Comment: Did any one figured out solution for this?

Comment: How can we add the fields dynamically like `var array = [{productid:{type:"number"}},{productname:{type:"sting"}}....]`. Can we use the array for the fields instead

Comment: I am interested in setting the model of my dataSource after the dataSource has been instantiated as well.  Is this possible?  I'm not finding any way to accomplish it. The following does not work:  dataSource.reader.model = kendo.data.Model.define(model);